# UAC pop up red when upgrading installation created with installshield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uac

Does anyone know why when upgrading an installation that was created using installshield, the UAC would come up red as shown below.

[image: Red UAC]

It only happens when installing an upgrade for a current user installation. Also both the original install and the upgrade have been signed using the same certificate and I have ensured that the certificate and the Root CA are installed.

Answer (score 0):

This article implies that the program (strictly speaking the publisher) has been blocked and will need a "run anyway" to start it:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070330-00/?p=27433/

A Windows Installer major upgrade is a fresh install that will remove the previously installed product if configured that way. It's still a new product that requires elevation. You may be thinking it's the same as UAC patching, but a major upgrade is not a patch, an msp file.